# CSS Flexbox space between divs with wrap

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have an outer `flexbox` with two inside `divs` next to each other, both of `150x150` size. Padding is `10px`. I use `flex-wrap: wrap;` so that if the window doesn't fit them both, the second one to go below the first.

```css
.big {
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.small1 {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}

.small2 {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="big">
  <div class="small1">Test1</div>
  <div class="small2">Test2</div>
</div>
```

How can I add another `10 pixels space` between them two, even if one is next or below the other? I tried several variations on the inner divs with `margin-left` and `margin-top` but all didn't give my result because one may work horizontally but won't vertically...

[image]

Comment: Horizontaly and vertically, 10px when the yellow div ends and starts the blue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a padding of 5px to the parent and and margin of 5px to the children.

```
.big {
    background-color: red;
    display: flex;
    padding: 5px;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.small1 {
    background-color: yellow;
    margin: 5px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
}
.small2 {
    background-color: blue;
    margin: 5px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
}
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/3htv9tgy/

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```css
.big {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 5px;
  background: red;
}

.small1, .small2 {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 5px;
  background: yellow;
}

.small2 {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="big">
  <div class="small1">Test1</div>
  <div class="small2">Test2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use media queries.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
.big {
    background-color: red;
    display: flex;
    padding: 10px;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.small1 {
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
}
.small2 {
    background-color: blue;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
}
@media (max-width:345px) {
    .small2 {
        margin-top:10px;
      margin-left:0px;
    }
    .small1
    {
      margin-right:10px;
    }

    @media (max-width:200px){
      .small1
      {
        margin-right:0px;
      }
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="big">
    <div class="small1">Test1</div>
    <div class="small2">Test2</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```